# What are the best ways to connect to SQL - Server from Restful API (aspnetcore)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Exploring some efficient ways to connect from Restful API to SQL Server written in ASPNETCORE2.2 and 3.x. Entity Framework I tried and its fine but really wanted to understand any other ways to connect to elevate performance.

Answer (score 0):

Dapper, Dapper contrib are latest lightweight and useful library for data layer. You can add to your project from below links.

[dapper contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/)
[dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/)

Comment: Thanks, what about directly creating a SQL connection without any ORM in place. Would that be a good idea.

Comment: maybe, it can cause sql injections, also you can directly load sql execution result to dto thanks to dapper library.